# Replacement for Crypto Random Bytes function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, cryptojs

Currently trying to generate a random buffer of size x in javascript/node/typescript, seems like the most common way to do this is using the `crypto` library

However, I'm having compilation issues with this library, as I'm using a bundler for a browser extension. Gives me the following error `Failed to resolve 'stream' from '/Users/moizahmed/Documents/node\_modules/cipher-base/index.js'`

I'm also only using one function from the crypto library, the `randomBytes` function, and was wondering if I could do this all without the use of a library?

Seems pretty trivial in other languages, not sure how to get this in javascript without the crypto library

Comment: The crypto library contains nodejs-specific things (like nodejs streams) that aren't supported in the browser.  So, when you try to pull that whole library in for the browser environment, it's missing things it needs.  You could manually go into the library and extra just the code you need (which doesn't need streams).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential work around which I've currently implemented

```
const randomBytes = () => {
    function randomString(length, chars) {
        var result = '';
        for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        return result;
    }
    var rString = randomString(4, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    const buf1 = Buffer.from(rString, 'hex');
    return buf1
}
```

Seems to get the job done, but curious as to whether there's better solutions

Comment: Whether this is adequate randomness depends upon what you're doing with it and what your requirements are.  It creates a random buffer that is as random as `Math.random()` is when combined with your relatively small set of characters you're using (only 36 as opposed to the whole 256 range of a byte).